# Adding/Subtracting in binary and hexadecimal formats?

Tags: binary, hex

I have two numbers(in decimal):

```
M = 3892.74
N = 9341.65
```

I am trying to add and subtract them in binary numbers and then in hexadecimal numbers. I manage to convert the numbers into binary/ hexadecimal with 4 fraction digits.

```
M = 111100110100.1011   and M = f34.bd70
N = 10010001111101.1010 and N = 247d.a666
```

and I have found `M + N = 13234.51 = 11001110110010.0101 = 33b2.83d6`
  I am having trouble doing the M - N ? Is there negative numbers in alternate number systems and how would I carry out this subtraction ? If my earlier work can be verified, I would also appreciate it. Thanks

Comment: If you're doing this by hand, you can just put a negative sign in front like you normally would with decimal numbers.

Comment: Use binary `2's complement` to make one of the numbers negative, then subtract by adding the 2's complement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

M - N can be done in the usual way as:

```
  00111100110100.1011 -  
  10010001111101.1010 
---------------------
1 10101010110111.0001
---------------------
```

We have a borrow here. Answer is negative and is in 2's complement form.

Or you can add the [2's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) of N with M.

```
-N = 2's complement of N = 101101110000010.0110

 0 00111100110100.1011 +  
 1 01101110000010.0110 
  ---------------------
 1 10101010110111.0001
  ---------------------
```

Take the 2's complement of this number to get `-01010101001000.1111 = -5448.9375`.